# Using to_json to include nested information from a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a nested method that I'd like to output via to_json:

`Venue` has a method called `published_events` that returns events that are published:

```
def published_events

    events_array = []

    self.events.each do |event|
      if event.published
        events_array << event
      end
    end

    events_array

  end
```

`Event` has a `to_param` method on it that I'd like to include in the json rendering of `Venue`:

```
format.json { render :json => @venue.to_json(:methods => :published_events => {:include => :to_param}) }
```

This, of course, doesn't work to include the to_param method of events. Is there another way I should go about this or will I need to build my own json? Is there a way in the `published_events` method that I can include the to_param method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 @venue.to_json(:include => {:published_events => {:method => :to_param}})
```

Comment: Wow... that worked (did have to change it to ":methods" pluralized)! Can't believe I missed it! :D